# upgrade maven in linux distribution for windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt, maven

I want to update to the newest version of maven in Windows subsystem for Linux. But using apt install gets the version 3.0.5, while in "windows" I already installed the version 3.3.9.

Is there any way to install the version 3.3.9? 
is it safe to just overwrite the files?

Comment: Try to download it in tarball and then install it [link](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

Comment: Alternative: chroot to dthis docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/